# How do we count rows using older versions of Hibernate (~2009)?

Tags: java, hibernate, count

For example, if we have a table Books, how would we count total number of book records with hibernate?

Answer (score 310, accepted):

**For older versions of Hibernate (<5.2):**

Assuming the class name is Book:

```
return (Number) session.createCriteria("Book")
                  .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
                  .uniqueResult();
```

It is at least a `Number`, most likely a `Long`.

Comment: As @Salandur suggests, "It is at least a Number", and Number type has  "intValue()", "longValue()" methods, so we can easily get the desired primitive type we want: ((Number) criteria.uniqueResult()).intValue()

Comment: It returns a type of `Object`.

Comment: If the entity mapping is unable to be found using a string parameter to the create criteria method, session.createCriteria(Book.class) can also be used

Comment: Like @MontyBongo said, I actually had to refer to the class like this: 
                             
  
    `return (Number) session.createCriteria(Book.class).setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();`

Comment: Actualy, Hibernate also maps the class name (Book in this case) as a entity name. So you can both use the entity name ("Book") as the class name (Book.class). But if you have 2 entity mappings on the same class than you should use the enityname, otherwise both entity mappings will be loaded.

Comment: But If the number of rows in the table is more than what Long can hold , then what do we cast to?

Comment: Then you should not use a rational database ;). Max value of long is 9,223372037×10¹⁸, which is laaaaaaaaaarge

Comment: how can you get the row count with connection?

Comment: @dj_segfault are you sure it returns a long always? It can depend on the driver and the DBMS flavour I guess.

Comment: createCriteria is deprecated since 5.2.

Answer (score 102):

In Java i usually need to return int and use this form:

```
int count = ((Long)getSession().createQuery("select count(*) from Book").uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

Comment: The accepted answer for this question didn't work for me, but yours did.  Thanks!

Comment: is this the fastest and cheapest way for getting count of a query? i mean hibernate-wise

Comment: What's the point of using an ORM if we end up coding SQL anyway?

Comment: That's my main concern (using SQL instead of HQL). I have to use nested SELECT just to count number of rows that comes after left outer join (I did not find proper implementation of left outer join in hibernate).

Comment: First off, this solution doesn't use SQL, it's HQL. And using count(*) instead of 'select count(e) from E e' or criteria works with @EmbeddedId and databases that don't support tuple count (eg. MySQL, where queries like 'select count((a,b)) from table1' doesn't work).

Comment: Why don't just cast directly to Integer, and let the unboxing do its work?? Please, is there an explaination?

Comment: The latest version of Hibernate (5.1.9.final at the time of writing) makes it very hard to do a simple conditional querying, so I'd prefer this method.

Comment: @thermz That's why ORM are leaky abstractions. Very clear in this case.

Answer (score 42):

Here is what [official hibernate docs tell](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-tipstricks) us about this:

You can count the number of query results without returning them:

```
( (Integer) session.createQuery("select count(*) from ....").iterate().next() ).intValue()
```

However, it doesn't always return `Integer` instance, so it is better to use `java.lang.Number` for safety.

Comment: +1 for an answer that gives the Hibernate team recommended method.

Comment: For me this gave "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer" but casting to a Long instead works...

Comment: @rogerdpack this is because Hibernate changed the returned type in 3.5 to Long:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide35

Comment: The return type for the count function can be found in `org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.CountFunction` (_StandardBasicTypes.LONG_)

Answer (score 12):

You could try `count(*)`

```
Integer count = (Integer) session.createQuery("select count(*) from Books").uniqueResult();
```

Where `Books` is the name off the `class` - not the table in the database.

Comment: sorry but its not working with Java and Hibernate :(

( I did replace int with Integer, as it is in Java for type casting. )

Comment: It should work - with Integer instead of int ? You need to put the class name in the HQL, not the table name - is the only thing I can think that may be wrong

Comment: I believe the post directly below this is more in line with the core Hibernate principles.

Comment: for me its not working with java and hibernate. what to do instead?

Answer (score 6):

```
Long count = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from  Book").uniqueResult();
```

Comment: It should be``` Long count = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(1) from  Book").uniqueResult();``` it will improve performance

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Hibernate 5+, then query will be modified as

```
Long count = session.createQuery("select count(1) from  Book")
                    .getSingleResult();
```

Or if you Need TypedQuery

```
Long count = session.createQuery("select count(1) from  Book",Long.class)
                        .getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Hibernate 4(Tested).

```
String hql="select count(*) from  Book";
Query query= getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
Long count=(Long) query.uniqueResult();
return count;
```

Where getCurrentSession() is:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


private Session getCurrentSession(){
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy, just run the following JPQL query:

```
int count = (
(Number)
    entityManager
    .createQuery(
        "select count(b) " +
        "from Book b")
    .getSingleResult()
).intValue();
```

The reason we are casting to `Number` is that some databases will return `Long` while others will return `BigInteger`, so for portability sake you are better off casting to a `Number` and getting an `int` or a `long`, depending on how many rows you are expecting to be counted.