# hibernate SQLquery extract variable

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

How can I extract variables total, min, max from hibernate SQL queries and assign them to java variables?

```
(select count(*) as total, min(price) as min, max(price) as max from product).addScalar("total", Hibernate.INTEGER).addScalar("min", Hibernate.INTEGER).addScalar("max", Hibernate.INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate) post should help you.

**Later edit:**

```
String sQuery = "select min(myEntity.x), max(myEntity.y) from MyEntity myEntity";
Query hQuery = session.createQuery(sQuery);
List result = hQuery.list();

Iterator iterator = result.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object[] row = (Object[])iterator.next();
    for (int col = 0; col < row.length; col++) {
        System.out.println(row[col]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to extract variables from SQL queries, without using criteria if it's possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Scalar queries return a `List` of `Object` arrays (`Object[]`) - or a single `Object[]` in your case.

It is however possible to return **non-managed entities** using a `ResultTransformer`. Quoting the [Hibernate 3.2: Transformers for HQL and SQL](http://relation.to/2133.lace) blog post:

> #### [SQL Transformers](http://relation.to/2133.lace#H-SQLTransformers)
>
> With native sql returning non-entity
>   beans or Map's is often more useful
>   instead of basic `Object[]`. With
>   result transformers that is now
>   possible.
>
> ```
> List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createSQLQuery(
>   "SELECT st.name as studentName, co.description as courseDescription " +
>   "FROM Enrolment e " +
>   "INNER JOIN Student st on e.studentId=st.studentId " +
>   "INNER JOIN Course co on e.courseCode=co.courseCode")
>   .addScalar("studentName")
>   .addScalar("courseDescription")
>   .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(StudentDTO.class))
>   .list();
>
> StudentDTO dto =(StudentDTO) resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
> ```
>
> Tip: the `addScalar()` calls were
>   required on HSQLDB to make it match a
>   property name since it returns column
>   names in all uppercase (e.g.
>   "STUDENTNAME"). This could also be
>   solved with a custom transformer that
>   search the property names instead of
>   using exact match - maybe we should
>   provide a `fuzzyAliasToBean()` method
>   ;)

#### See also

- [16.1.5. Returning non-managed entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904)

Comment: Never knew about resultTransformers. For now, I'm gonna stick to Object[]. Though, how should queries such as above be tested? I hate publishing it to server run it and time it. Is there a tool lets you test it without delpoying to local server?

Comment: @Nishant You can run Hibernate in a Java SE environment (e.g. a test case). Some IDEs are also offering HQL/Criteria editors (e.g. Hibernate Tools in Eclipse).