# How do we count rows using Hibernate with where clause?

Tags: java, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we count rows using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate)

How do we count rows using Hibernate with where clause?

```
select count(*) from table where recName = 'any'
```

Comment: I think this question already available,check the link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate

Comment: int count = (Integer) session.CreateQuery("select count(*) from table where recName = 'any'").UniqueResult();

Answer (score 5):

This questions was basically already answered on stackoverflow:

[How do we count rows using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate)

In addition to the solution using Projections you just have to add your where clause as an additional Criterion to the Criteria.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria("Book");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("title", "My Title"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
Number numRows = (Number)criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Count(*) from DomainClass d where d.someProperty='someValue'
```