# hibernate native query, count

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we count rows using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate)

I want count number of records by criteria in database.
I try use next query

```
String queryString = "SELECT Count(*) FROM my_table";  
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
```

but there is no method to execute this `Query query` and get result.
I know, that I can count records using

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM my_table";  
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString); 
query.getResultList().size();
```

so question, is query with `Count(*)` more performance, and if `yes`, then how can I execute query with `Count(*)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can execute your first query by calling `Query.getSingleResult()`, eg.

```
String queryString = "SELECT Count(*) FROM my_table";  
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString); 
System.out.println(query.getSingleResult());
```

If you want to assign the count to a variable you need to cast it to proper type (it can depend on DB but most likely it's Long).
The second query is very inefficient because Hibernate needs to retrieve entire table from DB, analyze it and then count all rows.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling query.getSingleResult()?