# How to rewrite sql statement to work with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL in my java application without ORM. I want to go further and add Hibernate to my project. I have this sql query which I add to PreparedStatement() and it returns a number.

```
SELECT COUNT(pr.id) FROM prisoner pr
JOIN cell c ON c.id = pr.cell_id
JOIN prison p ON p.id = c.prison_id
WHERE p.id = ?
```

I'm new to Hibernate. How would you suggest me to rewrite this statement to work with Hibernate? Should I use HSQL, or criteria or query or something different ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it Either of following way.

1) Keep you query as it and use nativeSQL for hibernate.

[hibernate native query, count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049137/hibernate-native-query-count)

2) make model of all your join table and put hibernate query.