# Hibernate Running native SQL Select

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, integer

I am trying to run a simple SQL(native) query within a hibernate application.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from users
```

The answer to the select may be saved into a integer.
How can i do this without having to create a model class in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;    
Resultset rs=Statement.ExecuteQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as count from users");
    if(rs.next()){
     count=rs.getInt("count");
    }

System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 5.0.9.Final will give that result as a `BigInteger` type object. Assuming you have an `EntityManager`, then use:

```
BigInteger r = (BigInteger) em.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from user").getSingleResult();
System.out.println(r);
```

This is a simple question and you should be able to find the answer easily on stackoverflow:

[hibernate native query, count [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049137/hibernate-native-query-count).

[How do we count rows using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate)

Answer (score -1):

```
Resultset rs=Statement.ExecuteQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as number from users");
while(rs.next()){
 Long count =rs.getLong("number");
    }
```

Comment: This will give error as you are trying to get a long from rs but storing it in an integer . Change int count to long count

Comment: yeah ,i just write it quickly anyway thanks to correct ;)