# Count rows in the result of a query in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm facing the following problem:

```
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);

    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.countDistinct("friend_id"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("registrationDate"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("lastLoginDate"));

    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
```

this piece of code returns me a couple of entries with the data I require. However, I need the rowcount for it. Is there a clean way of doing this, rather than just doing a:

```
return criteria.list().size();
```

?

Comment: Yes, there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate

Comment: Sorry, had to change the query to something closer to what I'm using, I did check that answer but it didn't really answer my question. There's a countDistinct within the query and using plain count will give me the wrong number of entries.

Comment: Good you have found a solution. It's better to post and accept it as your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that my problem was caused by the lack of analysis:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("id"));

return (Long) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

since we're already grouping by the user ID then all I had to do is find the amount if unique user IDs matching the search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Track.class)
                    .setProjection(Projections.rowCount());

            List result = criteria.list();
            if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                Integer rowCount = (Integer) result.get(0);
                System.out.println("Total records: " + rowCount);
```

Comment: This approach overrides the projection list, causing the data row count to be incorrect. Notice there's a 'count distinct' within the projection list which groups users and counts how many different friend_id's they have assigned.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add this to the end of the ProjectionList?

```
Projections.rowCount()
```

I use the following code to search something and then get the rowcount for it.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(LogEntryOracle.class);
if (search != null && !search.isEmpty()) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("xml", search, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
}

criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
return (Number) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: I've found the solution to my issue, I'll update the post with my solution. I didn't try this solution as I found a simpler approach to it.