# class cast exception in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, classcastexception

Test.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter reporting manager empid");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer in = sc.nextInt();
Session session=new  AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
 Query query=session.createQuery("select count(*)from MisRecords where empReportingManagerId=:i");
 query.setParameter("i", in);
    List<MisRecords> list=query.list();{
    for(MisRecords employee:list){
        //  System.out.println(employee.getFirstName());
        //  System.out.println(employee.getLastName());
         // System.out.println(employee.getEmpId());
          System.out.println(employee.getFirstName()+" "+ employee.getEmpId()+ " "+employee.getEmpReportingManagerId());

     }
MisRecords.java

@Entity
@Table(name="dat_emprecords")
public class MisRecords {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="pk_EmpRec_Idx")
    int id;

    @Column(name="EmpRec_EmpFName")
    String firstName;
    @Column(name="EmpRec_EmpLName")
    String lastName;
    @Column(name="fk_EmpRec_EmpID")
    int empId;
    @Column(name="fk_emprec_empreportingmgrid")
    int empReportingManagerId;
```

//output
    Enter reporting manager empid
    1
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to com.saurabh.MisRecords
        at com.saurabh.Test.main(Test.java:17)

When i am trying to run i am getting this classCastException ,Don't know why?
please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4290677/3094731) link..it might help you with your issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment, I see that you are trying to see record count,

> i want to see how many records are there instead to select all records

For that use below code snippet,

```
Query query=session.createQuery("select count(*)from MisRecords where empReportingManagerId=:i");
Long recordCount = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query is returning the `count` of results which is long. Please do :

`select * from MisRecords where empReportingManagerId=:i`

insetad of

`select count(*)from MisRecords where empReportingManagerId=:i` to get the results from the query.

If you want the count, you can do the following:

```
Query query=session.createQuery("select count(*)from MisRecords where empReportingManagerId=:i");
query.setParameter("i", in);
Iterator itr =query.iterator();
int i = 0;
if(itr.hasNext()){
    i = itr.next().intValue();
}
```

Comment: i want to see how many records are there instead to select all records

Comment: Then you should not be doing the following operation on that : `List<MisRecords> list=query.list();` As you know the result of the query is Long and not MisRecords.

Comment: You might do a query.iterate() and take the first result in the Long variable.

Comment: int a=( (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from  MisRecords where empReportingManagerId=1").iterate().next() ).intValue(); ,i found this solution ,but here i am hard coding the id,how i can provide value from scanner

Comment: its correct but this answer Query query=session.createQuery("select count(*)from MisRecords where empReportingManagerId=:i");
Long recordCount = (Long) query.uniqueResult(); is more efficient ,i will upvote your answer but.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a long from your query because you are using select count, if you wanna retrieve all the entities use from entity or select e from entity e

Answer (score 3):

You have used count(*) in your query. Thats why it will give result as a long value. if you want to get only count then you can execute the query and after that do query.iterate() and take the first result in long variable.

Comment: int a=( (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from  MisRecords where empReportingManagerId=1").iterate().next() ).intValue(); ,i found this solution ,but here i am hard coding the id,how i can provide value from scanner

Comment: You can use direct variable name in the query. like this -
int a=( (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from MisRecords where empReportingManagerId="+VARIABLE_NAME).iterate().next() ).intValue();

Answer (score 0):

I think its better for u

```html
Long value=hibernateTemplate.find(""select count(*)from MisRecords where empReportingManagerId=?,i);
```